# angular ng-repeat more than 1 alias

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, alias, angularjs-limitto

Is possible more than 1 alias in ng-repeat follow example ?

```
ng-repeat="dt in data | limitTo: reportCtrl.rowsLimit as rows1 | limitTo: reportCtrl.tableParams.rowsLim: (reportCtrl.tableParams.currentPage - 1) * reportCtrl.tableParams.rowsLim as rows2"
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. The limitTo filter restricts the number of rows that get rendered into the DOM. How can there logically be two limits?

Comment: Yeah, a limit depend other.